# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access denied

Tags: python, matplotlib, oserror

I installed the package matplotlib for a project and everything worked fine.
After a pull from github i got introduced with the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'.

I then tried to reinstall matplotlib with this code in the terminal : python3 -m pip install matplotlib.
I tried pip upgrade and other things but this error kept returning :

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access denied

Is there anybody that has an idea how to fix this?

[image: Picture:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this first if second step throws error

```
python3 -m pip install matplotlib --user
```

Comment: Tried this already but still gave the same error: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access denied

Comment: Just edited...Try & let me know

Comment: I tried to run the first line and got this error Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install --user --upgrade pip': The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: Updated try know

Comment: hmm this came up now:  ERROR: Invalid requirement: '--upgrade'

Comment: Re start laptop & Launch vscode as `Admin` by right clicking on it & then above snippet that I've edited & let me know

Comment: If it worked accept as a answer please